# Check textField in each row of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, is-empty

This is the situation :
I have a tableView with 3 rows. In this tableView, there is one tableVIewCell prototype with a textField. This textField is used in each row of tableView (differently).
My question is : how to check if each textField is empty ? I guess an If Statement but I don’t understand how to check all the textFields separately. Anyone could help me, please ?

An example of my tableView:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img540/2130/UsUNO3.png

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this exact thing in the past, here's the method I used:

```
for index in 0...(cellCount - 1) {

            var indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
            if let cellAtIndex = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpath) as? ContestantsTableViewCell {
                var newContestantString = cellAtIndex.contestantNameField.text

                if !newContestantString.isEmpty {
                    contestants.append(newContestantString)
                }
            }
        }
```

I just get the cell at the index path using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and get the property from the cell by casting it as my custom type.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that only 3 cells will be displayed all the time then you can keep reference to each cell and each cell textField and check length when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your textfield can be checked in each row by using indexpath.row(Tableview)

```
if(indexpath.row == 0){
    if(cell.textfield.text == "")
    {
      //1st textfiled empty
    }

}
else if(indexpath.row == 1){
  if(cell.textfield.text == "")
    {
      //2nd textfiled empty
    }
}
else if(indexpath.row == 2){
 if(cell.textfield.text == "")
    {
      //3rd textfiled empty
    }
}
```

Comment: this will work but how can we append all of the textfields texts in the cells  into array?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can create the function like below.You can use this function for any number of cell do not use `if else` condition. You can also use this function as textField Validation.

```
func getCellsDataOn() -> Bool {
        for section in 0 ..< self.tableView.numberOfSections {
            for row in 0 ..< self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as! YourCell
                if (cell.txtField!.text! != "") {
                    print("Not Empty")
                    //Handle your function 
                }else {
                    print("Empty")
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Hope this help Thanks.